# Regex match digits between strings

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I need to extract integer values from the following text, between strings "start:" and "end:", and **only** between.

```
 111222 garbage  999888 start:        123456       end:     start:         654321     end:
```

wanted results:

```
123456
654321
```

Here is what I have, but I need it to exclude the unknown number of spaces around the integer.

std::regex

```
(?<=start:)(.*?)(?=end:)
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com/3rg9q)

Comment: Can't you just use `([0-9]*)`?

Comment: @ResetACK Where do I put it? That is what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: That should work as your regex query, you shouldn't need to specify where the pattern occurs.

Comment: @ResetACK sry, I should have made better example, the thing is that integers can occur in other places too, that is why I need to match only those between two specific strings

Comment: You might capture one or more digits in a group: [`start:\s*(\d+)(?=\s*end:)`](https://regex101.com/r/OOWvDB/1)

Comment: What regex library are you using? `std::regex` or `boost::regex`? PCRE? PCRE2? Do you want to get a vector of strings with `123456` and `654321` values?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use std:regex

Comment: Ok, so your solution won't work since there is a lookbehind in the patterns. I suggest [this code](https://ideone.com/E6ebNm). `reg(R"(start:\s*(\d+)\s*end:)")` and grab Group 1 captures from all matches.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/E6ebNm

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Please post the answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
std::regex reg(R"(start:\s*(\d+)\s*end:)");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MaKKHO/2).

It defines the `start:\s*(\d+)\s*end:` regex pattern that matches `start:`, 0+ whitespaces, then captures into Group 1 one or more digits, and then matches 0+ whitespaces and `end:` substring.

Note that in case you cannot use raw string literals (`R"(...)"` notation), you may define the pattern with a regular string literal where all backslashes should be doubled: `"start:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*end:"`.

To obtain all matches, you need `std::sregex_token_iterator` and when getting the matches, specify that you need to grab all Group 1 values:

```
const std::regex reg(R"(start:\s*(\d+)\s*end:)");
std::smatch match;
std::string s = "garbage 111222 garbage ... 999888 fewfew... start:        123456       end:     start:         654321     end:";
std::vector<std::string> results(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), reg, 1),
                           std::sregex_token_iterator());
```

See the [online C++ demo](https://ideone.com/E6ebNm)

If there can be any value inside `start:` and `end:`, replace `\d+` with `.*?` (matching any 0+ chars other than line break characters).

Answer (score 1):

To extract the integer values between `start:` and `end:` without a lookbehind you could capture one or more digits in a capturing group:

- Match `start:` followed by zero or more whitespace characters `\s*`
- `(/d+)` Capture one or more digits in a group
- `(?=\s*end:)` positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that asserts that what follows is zero or more whitespace characters and `end:`

[`start:\s*(\d+)(?=\s*end:)`](https://regex101.com/r/OOWvDB/1)

Comment: I'm getting an exception ' regex_error'.
I'm using std:regex

Comment: @Borna Ah ok, the second one does not use a lookbehind. I have removed the regex with the lookbehind from my anser.

Comment: Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to extract integer values from the following text, between strings "start:" and "end:", and **only** between.
>   `111222 garbage  999888 start:        123456       end:     start:         654321     end:`

You can use this: `start:\s*([0-9]+)`

```
int main()
{
    std::string str{R"(111222 garbage  999888 start:        123456       end:     start:         654321     end:)"};
    std::regex rgx{R"(start:\s*([0-9]+))"};
    std::smatch matches;

    while (std::regex_search(str, matches, rgx)) {
        std::cout << matches.str(1) << std::endl;
        str = matches.suffix();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
123456
654321
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://cpp.sh/8p2cd)</kbd>

Comment: There can be digits before and after `start:` and `end:`. OP specifically mentions that [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010366/regex-match-digits-between-string/51010792#comment89013442_51010366).

Comment: The `strart:\s*([0-9]+)`  pattern does not check for the trailing delimiter and `std::regex_search` only searches for the first pattern match. See my answer where I am using the `std::sregex_token_iterator` to iterate the string to get all matches.