# Regex match especific characters between 2 strings

Tags: regex

I have this json inside an appender:

```
{"message": "This is a "bad-json" message" "severity": "INFO"}
```

I need to match every double quotes inside the message to replace them with single quotes, leaving the other double quotes as they are, like this:

```
{"message": "This is a 'bad-json' message" "severity": "INFO"}
```

So I have a regex with positive look ahead and positive look behind:

```
(?<="message": ")(.*)(?=","severity")
```

But I don't know how to get only the quotes inside to do the replacement, I tried changing the `(.*)` part but it seems like is all or nothing and I haven't been able to capture only the double quotes.

Here's an example: [RegexR](https://regexr.com/4g0oc)

I've been looking at other answers but most of them whant all the characters I found this one [Regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010366/regex-match-digits-between-strings) but still not good enough.

EDIT:

Here are more samples:

```
{"message": "This is a "bad-json" message with "bad json" quotes","severity": "INFO"}
{"message": ""bad-json" message at start and end "bad json"","severity": "INFO"}
{"message": "many "bad-json" "bad-json" "bad-json", "bad-json" "bad-json" messages all over the place","severity": "INFO"}
```

Comment: Like [this](https://regexr.com/4g0pa)  perhaps, but this is a very fragile solution. You should have it fixed on the provider side.

Comment: This is working, why do you say its fragile?

Comment: I'm doing the replacement inside the LayoutAppender in log4j2 so there is not much room for editing the results

Comment: Does it use Java regex engine under the hood? Then you need `(\G(?!^)|"message": ")([^"]*)"(?=.*?","severity")` and replace with `$1$2` plus what you replace `"`  with.

Comment: yes it uses the java regex engine under the hood

Comment: Then my answer below is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(\G(?!^)|"message": ")([^"]*)"(?=.*?","severity")
```

And replace with `$1$2'`.

**Details**

- `(\G(?!^)|"message": ")` - Group 1: end of the previous match or `"message": "` substring
- `([^"]*)` - Group 2: any 0 or more chars other than double quote
- `"` - double quote
- `(?=.*?","severity")` - a positive lookahead that requires a `","severity"` substring after any 0 or more chars to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can for instance design a simple expression similar to:

```
(.*"message"\s*:\s*".*?)"(.*?)"(.*?"\s*".*)
```

and with this replacement:

```
$1'$2'$3
```

and it might work.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K4qvOm/1/)

Comment: hmmm I might get more than 2 quotes inside the message, I need to find all qoutes between message and severity... maybe grouping `"(.*?)`